# $X_1 + X_2 + \cdots $ far away from $0$

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variable, with $P(X_i = 0)\ne 1$.

I wish to prove that $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ satisfy $P(|S_n| \le A )\to 0$ for $\forall A > 0$, which means $S_n$ "almost far away from $0$".

If $E|X_i|<\infty$ it is a trivial corrolary of strong law of large number, but if $E X_i$ does not exist, is this still hold? Or there are some counterexamples?

Answer (score 0):

What if $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$ because the distribution is symmetric? Then $S_n$ will also have 0 expectation.

Comment: But This may still hold(If variance exists, it can be deduced from Central Limit Theorem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1028298)

Comment: @an4s it's not a critique, just a proof that the statement of the question is generally false. Showing requested claim is generally false is also an answer to the question.

Comment: @Focus No, not really -- by SLLN the average will converge to the expected value almost surely

Comment: But my statements may still be true. For example $\sqrt{n}/n \to 0$

Comment: @Focus If all $X_i$ are zero mean, $S_n \to 0$ so $$\mathbb{P}[|S_n| \le A] \to 1, \quad \forall A > 0.$$

Comment: But it is in fact $S_n/n \to 0$

Comment: @Focus Yes, $S_n/n \to 0$ by KSSLN but you are asking about $S_n$, not $S_n/n$

Comment: So $S_n$ not $\to$ 0

Comment: @Focus correct, since you are not even assuming $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$...